# Portable C++11 way to wait on a socket and bool var at the same time

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets, c++11

I have a thread with endless loop that receieves and processes data from a socket. I want that thread to block (sleep) until the data becomes available on the socket for reading or the "exit" boolean variable becomes true (set by a different thread). Is it possible to do that in a portable way *without* polling and using any third-party libraries (except sockets library naturally)? If it is not possible to do in a portable way what would be the best way to do it under Windows (still NO polling and third-party libraries)?

Example code:

```
bool exit = false; // or "std::atomic<bool> exit" or anything else
void fn()
{
    SOCKET s;
    // init socket, establish connection, etc
    for(;;)
    {
        // This thread goes to wait (blocks) until data becomes available on socket
        // OR exit var is set to true (by a different thread) - how?
        if(exit) break;
        // receive and process data from socket
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are asking requires an unified event handling framework. At this time even boost doesn't provide this. For windows the answer is `WaitForMultipleObjects` afaik.

Comment: btw, you will have to define exactly what you mean by "no polling", because `WaitForMultipleObjects` is a form of polling for me (as pretty much any function made to wait on events is).

Comment: @didierc I was afraid `WaitForMultipleObjects` is the only solution - all the fancy C++11 multithreading stuff is useless when you actually need any multithreading at all :( And "no polling" means no polling in my code - if OS specific routine does it - it's fine - I trust it to do it 10 times better then I ever can in my own code.

Comment: If you are waiting in a blocking manner then you generally can't wait on a bool as well. What you can do though is check a bool before a blocking wait. In order to cancel the wait you can add a dummy pipe (or similar) and write to it. This method works in most `select`, boost.asio and wait for multiple style frameworks.

Comment: I disagree. I think you could try a redesign of your app to use either `boost` or `stl`. Yet another option is to look into third party libraries which provide enough event abstraction for your need, even though you seem initially against this option (would you care to elaborate on the reasons?).

Comment: As @John5342 perhaps hinted to, another option is to emulate the cond var as write to a descriptor, hence allowing to poll on both regular files and cond var. Thinking about it, `atomic` aren't designed to be waited on, so I assumed you meant a cond var.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a queue of messages.

These messages are of the form "PleaseExit" or "DataOnSocket".

Your thread, or task, is activated when anything shows up in the queue, processes the queue, then waits on the queue again.  If it gets "PleaseExit" it instead starts cleaning up.

Possibly you will have to have a different thread/task waiting on the condition variable and on the socket to ferry the information over to your unified queue.

I say "thread or task", because having an entire thread dedicated to waiting is overkill.  Sadly, C++11 threading [doesn't support light weight tasks out of the box](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/10/10/async-tasks-in-c11-not-quite-there-yet/) perfectly.

Basically, this solution allows a thread to wait on multiple events by delegating the waiting on each event to other threads, which send notifications "up the pipe".  You could imagine creating a common infrastructure, where your thread that wants to wait on multiple objects tells the dispatch center what it is waiting for, then waits on its own condition condition variable.

The dispatch center waits on each of the things your thread wanted to wait for, and when they occur proceeds to figure out which threads should be notified, then notifies them.

Far, far from ideal, but it does let you do it in fully standards compliant C++11 land.  And can give you an interface much like "wait for multiple objects" from windows.  (In fact, on windows, you could do away with much of the machinery if the `native_handle` of your C++11 synchronization primitives are amenable).

Comment: This sounds a nice idea, but might it be better with a priority queue so that exit requests can be pushed to the front?

Comment: @Yakk I don't see how what you suggest solves the problem of somehow signaling the thread that waits for `FD_READ` notification on socket (using `select` or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` etc) to exit.

Comment: @PowerGamer The thread doesn't wait on the socket: The thread waits on the framework, which has a worker thread that waits on the socket, a worker thread that waits on the other signal, and when either arrive it relays them through the framework.  Interoperation with non-framework waiting events is impossible in some cases (as guaranteeing that you only consume a signal or a socket message, but not both, isn't possible), and it doesn't let you expose C++11 threading primitives outside the framework, but it should work.  C++11 threading is overly primitive at this point.

Comment: @Yakk Ok, so how do you signal the "worker thread that waits on the socket" to exit then?

Comment: @powergamer For non-C++11 events, you have to get the ability to signal the waiting thread.  In the case of a socket, you create your own controlled socket, and have the thread wait on both your socket and the external socket.  Similarly for waiting on a windows event you don't control -- create a windows event you do control, and have the waiting thread wait on multiple objects.  For C++11 event code, also ensure that the framework can wake the thread, possibly by firing the event in question itself.  Yes, it ends up being exceedingly messy.

Comment: @Yakk "In the case of a socket, you create your own controlled socket, and have the thread wait on both your socket and the external socket." - I thought about this too, but creating an extra network socket just for a simple purpose of signaling network thread to exit is such an overkill and feels plain wrong. Also, I am starting to wonder what is the point of blocking sockets (that are supposed to simplify your code) if you can't even properly signal a thread using blocking sockets to exit...